# Cruise Control .NET Security

Tags: ldap, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I am attempting to implement LDAP authentication, along with the required permissions.

```
<internalSecurity>
    <cache type="inMemoryCache" duration="60" mode="sliding" />
    <audit>
        <xmlFileAudit location="D:\Logs\CCNet_Audit.xml"/>
    </audit>
  <auditReader type="xmlFileAuditReader" location="D:\Logs\CCNet_Audit.xml"/>
  <users>
    <ldapUser name="*username*" domain="*localdomain*"/> 
  </users>
  <permissions>
    <rolePermission name="Admin" forceBuild="Allow" sendMessage="Allow" startProject="Allow" changeProject="Allow" viewSecurity="Allow" modifySecurity="Allow" viewProject="Allow" viewConfiguration="Allow" >
      <users>
        <userName name="*username*"/>
      </users>
    </rolePermission>
  </permissions>
```

Inside my project I have the following XML:

```
<project name="TestProject" description="TestProject" queue="Q7">
        <security type="defaultProjectSecurity" defaultRight="Deny">
            <permissions>
                <rolePermission name="Admin" ref="Admin"/>
            </permissions>
        </security>
```

My log at (D:\Logs\CCNet_Audit.xml) is saying that I am "Denied"

```
<event><dateTime>2015-08-17T09:30:41.7973762-04:00</dateTime><user>*username*</user><type>Login</type><outcome>Deny</outcome></event>
```

and the project is unavailable within CC Tray.

My username is correct and I have the domain correct within the configuration (I just don't want to share it).

One thing I have noticed is that There seems to be a case issue within the username that Cruise Control is getting c-Joe.smith versus the english "normalization" of c-Joe.Smith . . . and yes I have tried it both ways.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting defaultRight="Allow" for your admin group.

```
<rolePermission name="Admin" defaultRight="Allow" forceBuild="Allow" sendMessage="Allow" startProject="Allow" changeProject="Allow" viewSecurity="Allow" modifySecurity="Allow" viewProject="Allow" viewConfiguration="Allow" >
  <users>
    <userName name="*username*"/>
  </users>
</rolePermission>
```

Comment: Did that work for you? If so, please be so kind as to accept the answer. Thanks.